# AWS Redshift Copy Command Dynamic source file path

Tags: copy, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to pass in current_date to copy command for the S3 path

for ex : Copy tablename from 's3/rootlocation/**_current_date_**/*.txt in AWS Redshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John is correct, it's not possible to dynamically build the `COPY` statement. However, I found a way to work around this, using SQL only, with just a few more commands:

```sql
create temporary table _path as 
    select (
        '{"entries":[{"url":"s3://bucket/customer' || 
        getdate()::date || 
        '.txt", "mandatory":true}]}'
    )::varchar(255)
;

unload ('select * from _path') to 's3://bucket/customer.manifest'
credentials '' parallel off
;

copy customer from 's3://bucket/customer.manifest000' credentials '' manifest;
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html.

Answer (score 1):

My experiments have shown that the *FROM* parameter needs to be a single string, rather than a calculated value. Therefore it is **not possible** to do something like this:

```
copy customer
from 's3://mybucket/customer' + CURRENT_DATE
credentials '<aws-auth-args>';
```

You would need to calculate the string *prior to* sending it to Redshift, through whatever system you use to trigger the `COPY` command.

Another similar method is to use a [manifest file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html) that contains a list of files to load. This is useful in situations where many files are stored in a given directory and only some need to be loaded. It also avoids confusion as to which files were included in a load.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this silly issue, this is how I got around it:

```
create or replace procedure test(
    p_date date
)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    v_path varchar(255);
    v_copy_command varchar(max);
begin 

    select 's3://bucket/path/date_stamp='||p_date into v_path;
    raise notice 'Path is %', v_path;

    select 'COPY table FROM ''' ||
            v_path ||
            ''' REGION ''us-east-1'' IAM_ROLE ''arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/service-role/AmazonRedshift-CommandsAccessRole''    FORMAT as parquet;' 
                 into v_copy_command;
    raise notice 'Copy command: %', v_copy_command;

    execute v_copy_command;

end;
$$
```